# aes 128 encryption and decryption in c without any seperate libraries and header files needed mainly in diagnostics point of view

Tags: c, encryption, aes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define Nb 4
#define Nk 4
#define Nr 10

uint8_t state[4 * Nb];
uint8_t w[Nb * (Nr + 1) * 4];

#define mul2(x) ((x << 1) ^ (((x >> 7) & 1) * 0x1b))
#define mul3(x) (mul2(x) ^ x)
#define mul9(x) (mul2(mul2(mul2(x))) ^ x)
#define mul11(x) (mul2(mul2(mul2(x)) ^ x) ^ x)
#define mul13(x) (mul2(mul2(mul2(x) ^ x)) ^ x)
#define mul14(x) (mul2(mul2(mul2(x) ^ x) ^ x))
```

i dont want to use lookup table for xor multiplications so used this above method as reference to caliculate the values runtime

```
uint8_t sbox[256] = {
  0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76,
  0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0,
  0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15,
  0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75,
  0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84,
  0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf,
  0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8,
  0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2, 
  0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73, 
  0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb,
  0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79,
  0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08, 
  0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a, 
  0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e,
  0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf,
  0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16
};

uint8_t inv_sbox[256] = {
  0x52, 0x09, 0x6a, 0xd5, 0x30, 0x36, 0xa5, 0x38, 0xbf, 0x40, 0xa3, 0x9e, 0x81, 0xf3, 0xd7, 0xfb,
  0x7c, 0xe3, 0x39, 0x82, 0x9b, 0x2f, 0xff, 0x87, 0x34, 0x8e, 0x43, 0x44, 0xc4, 0xde, 0xe9, 0xcb,
  0x54, 0x7b, 0x94, 0x32, 0xa6, 0xc2, 0x23, 0x3d, 0xee, 0x4c, 0x95, 0x0b, 0x42, 0xfa, 0xc3, 0x4e,
  0x08, 0x2e, 0xa1, 0x66, 0x28, 0xd9, 0x24, 0xb2, 0x76, 0x5b, 0xa2, 0x49, 0x6d, 0x8b, 0xd1, 0x25,
  0x72, 0xf8, 0xf6, 0x64, 0x86, 0x68, 0x98, 0x16, 0xd4, 0xa4, 0x5c, 0xcc, 0x5d, 0x65, 0xb6, 0x92,
  0x6c, 0x70, 0x48, 0x50, 0xfd, 0xed, 0xb9, 0xda, 0x5e, 0x15, 0x46, 0x57, 0xa7, 0x8d, 0x9d, 0x84,
  0x90, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x00, 0x8c, 0xbc, 0xd3, 0x0a, 0xf7, 0xe4, 0x58, 0x05, 0xb8, 0xb3, 0x45, 0x06,
  0xd0, 0x2c, 0x1e, 0x8f, 0xca, 0x3f, 0x0f, 0x02, 0xc1, 0xaf, 0xbd, 0x03, 0x01, 0x13, 0x8a, 0x6b,
  0x3a, 0x91, 0x11, 0x41, 0x4f, 0x67, 0xdc, 0xea, 0x97, 0xf2, 0xcf, 0xce, 0xf0, 0xb4, 0xe6, 0x73,
  0x96, 0xac, 0x74, 0x22, 0xe7, 0xad, 0x35, 0x85, 0xe2, 0xf9, 0x37, 0xe8, 0x1c, 0x75, 0xdf, 0x6e,
  0x47, 0xf1, 0x1a, 0x71, 0x1d, 0x29, 0xc5, 0x89, 0x6f, 0xb7, 0x62, 0x0e, 0xaa, 0x18, 0xbe, 0x1b,
  0xfc, 0x56, 0x3e, 0x4b, 0xc6, 0xd2, 0x79, 0x20, 0x9a, 0xdb, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0x78, 0xcd, 0x5a, 0xf4,
  0x1f, 0xdd, 0xa8, 0x33, 0x88, 0x07, 0xc7, 0x31, 0xb1, 0x12, 0x10, 0x59, 0x27, 0x80, 0xec, 0x5f,
  0x60, 0x51, 0x7f, 0xa9, 0x19, 0xb5, 0x4a, 0x0d, 0x2d, 0xe5, 0x7a, 0x9f, 0x93, 0xc9, 0x9c, 0xef,
  0xa0, 0xe0, 0x3b, 0x4d, 0xae, 0x2a, 0xf5, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0xeb, 0xbb, 0x3c, 0x83, 0x53, 0x99, 0x61,
  0x17, 0x2b, 0x04, 0x7e, 0xba, 0x77, 0xd6, 0x26, 0xe1, 0x69, 0x14, 0x63, 0x55, 0x21, 0x0c, 0x7d

};

uint8_t rcon[256] = {
0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a,
0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39,
0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a,
0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8,
0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef,
0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc,
0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b,
0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3,
0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94,
0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20,
0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35,
0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f,
0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04,
0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63,
0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd,
0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d
};


uint32_t sub_bytes_word(uint32_t word) {
  uint8_t* bytes = (uint8_t*)&word;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    bytes[i] = sbox[bytes[i]];
  }
  return word;
}

uint32_t inv_sub_bytes_word(uint32_t word) {
  uint8_t* bytes = (uint8_t*)&word;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    bytes[i] = inv_sbox[bytes[i]];
  }
  return word;
}

uint32_t rot_word(uint32_t word) {
  return (word << 8) | (word >> 24);
}

uint32_t sub_word(uint32_t word) {
  return sub_bytes_word(word);
}

uint32_t inv_word(uint32_t word) {
  return inv_sub_bytes_word(word);
}


void key_expansion(uint8_t* key) {
  for (int i = 0; i < Nk; i++) {
    w[i] = key[4 * i] << 24 | key[4 * i + 1] << 16 | key[4 * i + 2] << 8 | key[4 * i + 3];
  }
  for (int i = Nk; i < 4 * (Nr + 1); i++) {
    uint32_t temp = w[i - 1];
    if (i % Nk == 0) {
      temp = sub_word(rot_word(temp)) ^ rcon[i / Nk - 1];
    } else if (Nk > 6 && i % Nk == 4) {
      temp = sub_word(temp);
    }
    w[i] = w[i - Nk] ^ temp;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * (Nr + 1); i++) {
    w[i] = inv_word(w[i]);
  }
}



void sub_bytes() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
    state[i] = sbox[state[i]];
  }
}

void shift_rows() {
  uint8_t temp[4 * Nb];
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
    temp[i] = state[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < Nb; i++) {
    state[i] = temp[i];
    state[i + 4] = temp[i + 4];
    state[i + 8] = temp[i + 8];
    state[i + 12] = temp[i + 12];
  }
  state[1] = temp[5];
  state[5] = temp[9];
  state[9] = temp[13];
  state[13] = temp[1];
  state[2] = temp[10];
  state[6] = temp[14];
  state[10] = temp[2];
  state[14] = temp[6];
  state[3] = temp[15];
  state[7] = temp[3];
  state[11] = temp[7];
  state[15] = temp[11];
}

void mix_columns() {
  uint8_t temp[4 * Nb];
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
    temp[i] = state[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < Nb; i++) {
    state[0 + 4 * i] = mul2(temp[0 + 4 * i]) ^ mul3(temp[1 + 4 * i]) ^ temp[2 + 4 * i] ^ temp[3 + 4 * i];
    state[1 + 4 * i] = temp[0 + 4 * i] ^ mul2(temp[1 + 4 * i]) ^ mul3(temp[2 + 4 * i]) ^ temp[3 + 4 * i];
    state[2 + 4 * i] = temp[0 + 4 * i] ^ temp[1 + 4 * i] ^ mul2(temp[2 + 4 * i]) ^ mul3(temp[3 + 4 * i]);
    state[3 + 4 * i] = mul3(temp[0 + 4 * i]) ^ temp[1 + 4 * i] ^ temp[2 + 4 * i] ^ mul2(temp[3 + 4 * i]);
  }
}

void add_round_key(int round) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
    state[i] ^= w[round * 4 * Nb + i];
  }
}

void aes_round(int round) {
  sub_bytes();
  shift_rows();
  mix_columns();
  add_round_key(round);
}

void inv_sub_bytes() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
    state[i] = inv_sbox[state[i]];
  }
}
void inv_shift_rows() {
  uint8_t temp[4 * Nb];
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
    temp[i] = state[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < Nb; i++) {
    state[i] = temp[i];
    state[i + 4] = temp[i + 4];
    state[i + 8] = temp[i + 8];
    state[i + 12] = temp[i + 12];
  }
  state[1] = temp[13];
  state[5] = temp[1];
  state[9] = temp[5];
  state[13] = temp[9];
  state[2] = temp[10];
  state[6] = temp[14];
  state[10] = temp[2];
  state[14] = temp[6];
  state[3] = temp[7];
  state[7] = temp[11];
  state[11] = temp[15];
  state[15] = temp[3];
}

void inv_mix_columns() {
  uint8_t temp[4 * Nb];
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
    temp[i] = state[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < Nb; i++) {
    state[0 + 4 * i] = mul14(temp[0 + 4 * i]) ^ mul11(temp[1 + 4 * i]) ^ mul13(temp[2 + 4 * i]) ^ mul9(temp[3 + 4 * i]);
    state[1 + 4 * i] = mul9(temp[0 + 4 * i]) ^ mul14(temp[1 + 4 * i]) ^ mul11(temp[2 + 4 * i]) ^ mul13(temp[3 + 4 * i]);
    state[2 + 4 * i] = mul13(temp[0 + 4 * i]) ^ mul9(temp[1 + 4 * i]) ^ mul14(temp[2 + 4 * i]) ^ mul11(temp[3 + 4 * i]);
    state[3 + 4 * i] = mul11(temp[0 + 4 * i]) ^ mul13(temp[1 + 4 * i]) ^ mul9(temp[2 + 4 * i]) ^ mul14(temp[3 + 4 * i]);
  }
}

void inv_aes_round(int round) {
  add_round_key(round);
  inv_mix_columns();
  inv_shift_rows();
  inv_sub_bytes();
}
```

Here i tried encrypt and decrypt the plain text

```
void encrypt(uint8_t* plaintext, uint8_t* key) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
    state[i] = plaintext[i];
  }
  key_expansion(key);
  add_round_key(0);
  for (int i = 1; i <= Nr; i++) {
    aes_round(i);
  }
}

void decrypt(uint8_t* ciphertext, uint8_t* key) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
    state[i] = ciphertext[i];
  }
  key_expansion(key);
  add_round_key(Nr);
  for (int i = Nr - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    inv_aes_round(i);
  }
  inv_aes_round(0);
}
```

My main function

```
int main() {
  // Set key and plaintext
  uint8_t key[16] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef};
  uint8_t plaintext[16] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef};
  uint8_t ciphertext[16];
  uint8_t decrypted[16];
  

  // Plaintext
    printf("Original plaintext:  ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", plaintext[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  // Encrypt plaintext
  encrypt(plaintext, key);
  printf("Ciphertext: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", state[i]);
    ciphertext[i] = state[i];
  }
  printf("\n");
  
  // Decrypt ciphertext
  decrypt(ciphertext, key);
  printf("Decrypted:  ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", state[i]);
    decrypted[i] = state[i];
  }
  printf("\n");
  
  return 0;
}
```

i have tried improving the code many times by assigning seperate functions to implement but every time my output is wrong .\

This is my output ; whatever i tried iam not able to get correct decrypt . iam not sure where i did mistake .

Original plaintext:  01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef

Ciphertext: ec d5 9c a4 41 cb cb e5 08 02 a3 cc 7c 39 be 74

Decrypted:  37 b8 75 c5 01 5c 74 14 b4 e9 11 d8 3c 16 cd c2

Comment: Repost of [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75055287/aes-128-encryption-and-decryption-in-c-without-any-seperate-libraries-and-header)

Comment: @dbush indeed ,i have made the changes mentioned in the previous post comments as its closed and added new tables

Comment: Test with the [Known Answer Tests](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/aes/AESAVS.pdf) and report the results.

Comment: The question was closed for a reason, and you still have not provided a [mre]. There is [reference test data](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/aes/AESAVS.pdf) for AES, and you should be testing with it. Using that allows you to test encryption and decryption separately. Instead, you provided a test with both encryption and decryption, making it difficult to figure out whether one or both are wrong. That is not a [mre].

Comment: Further, you should provide a single source text that can be compiled and executed as a program. Instead, you pasted it in separate sections, making people who want to reproduce your results have to stitch them together. Do not make unnecessary work for other people. I did test your program, and it fails the Known Answer Tests on encryption. So you can get rid of the decryption code from this question; it is not needed to reproduce.

Comment: Then, you should perform unit tests on the individual routines.

Comment: Reposting a closed question may be considered abusive. Maybe you made changes in good faith, but you have not gone as far as you should have. You should put significant work into debugging your program and isolating the problem to small portions before posting it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you for your valuable time , will consider doing the individual tests  like you mentioned and report the results .

Comment: I set the key to all zeros and added code to the end of `key_expansion` to print the result of key expansion. My working implementation shows four words of “0x00000000”, then four “0x63636362”, then “0xc998989b”, “0xaafbfbf9”, and “0xc998989b”. Your code does not get that, so it goes wrong before even getting to the main part of encryption. In `key_expansion`, you have `w[i] = inv_word(w[i]);`, and `inv_word` is defined to take a `uint32_t` argument and return a `uint32_t` result, but `w` is defined to be an array of `uint8_t`. So I do not think you are handling the types correctly.

Comment: The line `w[i] = key[4 * i] << 24 | key[4 * i + 1] << 16 | key[4 * i + 2] << 8 | key[4 * i + 3];` confirms this; that prepares a 32-bit value to be assigned to an eight-bit value.